# Linear Interpolation in Python

Tags: python, linear-interpolation

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm trying to write a program that will do a 4-point linear interpolation reading data from a .txt file and asking for user information.

The .txt file has temperature and pressures in a table with this format:

```
T    P1  P2  P3  P4
     80,100,150,200
75,  400,405,415,430
100, 450,456,467,483
150, 500,507,519,536
200, 550,558,571,589
```

And here's the code:

```
# User input
temp = input("Enter temperature value in degrees Celcius [Range: 75-200]:")
pressure = input("Enter pressure value in bars [Range: 80-589")

temp = float(temp)
pressure = float(pressure)

# Opens file and read data
filename = open('xxxxxxxxxxxxx.txt', 'r').readlines()

# Removes \n from each line
for i in list(range((len(filename)-1))):
    filename[i] = filename[i][:-1]

# Splits string
for i in list(range(len(filename))):
    filename[i] = filename[i].split(',')

# Converts string numbers into decimal numbers
for i in [2,3,4,5,6]:
    filename[i][0] = float(filename[i][0])
    filename[i][1] = float(filename[i][1])
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. If the user input was say, T=100 and P=200, how would I locate the data points from the file that are directly before and after those numbers?

Obviously, I don't know much about what I'm doing, but I would appreciate any help.

ETA: Actual table values.
Also, I was not clear on the actual problem statement. Given a temperature and pressure, the program should perform an linear interpolation to find U (internal energy). The T values are the first column, the P values the first row, and the rest are U values.

Comment: Since whitespace is significant in Python, please make sure the original indentation is preserved when you paste code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate questions here: how to read data into python / NumPy,
and how to do 2d interpolatation.
For reading data, I'd suggest
[numpy loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html),
and for interpolation,
[scipy BivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html).
(They both have more options than you need.)

```
from __future__ import division
from cStringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

np.set_printoptions( 1, threshold=100, edgeitems=10, suppress=True )

    # a file inline, for testing --
myfile = StringIO( """
# T  P1  P2  P3  P4
0,   80,100,150,200

75,  400,405,415,430
100, 450,456,467,483
150, 500,507,519,536
200, 550,558,571,589
""" )

    # file -> numpy array --
    # (all rows must have the same number of columns)
TPU = np.loadtxt( myfile, delimiter="," )
P = TPU[0,1:]  # top row
T = TPU[ 1:,0]  # left col
U = TPU[1:,1:]  # 4 x 4, 400 .. 589
print "T:", T
print "P:", P
print "U:", U

interpolator = RectBivariateSpline( T, P, U, kx=1, ky=1 )  # 1 bilinear, 3 spline

    # try some t, p --
for t, p in (
    (75, 80),
    (75, 200),
    (87.5, 90),
    (200, 80),
    (200, 90),
    ):
    u = interpolator( t, p )
    print "t %5.1f  p %5.1f -> u %5.1f" % (t, p, u)
```

By the way, for interactive python,
[IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html)
makes it easy to try single lines, look at variables ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a *sorted* list of numbers, `x1, x2, x3... xn`, you could use the `bisect` module for fast location of the interval you want (`O(log n)`).

```
from bisect import bisect, bisect_right, bisect_left
#    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
x = [1,   2,   4,   8,  16, 100, 200, 300]


def find_interval(x,y):
    # x must be a sorted list.

    index = bisect_left(x,y)
    # Larger than largest element in x
    if index >= len(x):
        l,r = -1, None
    # Exactly equal to something in x
    elif y == x[index]:
        l,r = index, index
    # Smaller than smallest element in x
    elif index == 0:
        l,r = None, 0
    # Inbetween two elements in x
    else:
        l,r = index-1, index

    print (x[l] if l != None else "To left of all elements")
    print (x[r] if r != None else "To right of all elements")
    return (l,r)

>>> x
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 100, 200, 300]
>>> find_interval(x,0)
To left of all elements
1
>>> find_interval(x,1000)
300
To right of all elements
>>> find_interval(x,100)
100
100
>>> find_interval(x,12)
8
16
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `.readlines()` will shoot you in the foot as soon as the file gets big. Can you formulate what you need to do in terms of

   ```
   for line in open(...):
       # parse line
   ```

   and parse the file just once without loading it fully into memory.

   - Much better still, would be to use the `with` idiom when working with files:

     ```
     with open(...) as file:
         for line in file:
             # parse line
     ```

     This saves you a bit of headaches when there is a problem while working with the file.
2. You don't need to strip newlines if you will end up using `float()` to make a float out of a string. `float('1.2 \t\n')` is perfectly valid code.
3. `for i in list(range(len(filename))):`

   This is bad style. The Python idiom for iterating through a list is

   ```
   for element in list:
   ```

   If you need an index into the list, then you should use

   ```
   for i, element in enumerate(list):
   ```

   Your approach is sort-of "manual" and it works, but creating a `list` out of a `list` (coming from `range(...)` in python 2.x) is completely unnecessary. A better "manual" alternative to your code would be

   ```
   for i in xrange(len(filename)):
   ```

   but it is still much less readable than the idioms above.

Now that I'm done bashing on your code, the main question is: what [the hell] do you actually need done? Can you give us the exact, word-for-word, specification of the problem you are trying to solve?

- Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation?
- What is the significance of the input data from the terminal in your case?
- Why and what for do you need the data from the file that is just before and after the input data from the terminal?
- Is the temperature/pressure data somehow sorted?
- What do the lines in the file represent (e.g. are they time-based or location-based or something else)?
- What do the four different pressures represent?

Comment: I was not clear on the actual problem statement. Given a temperature and pressure, the program should perform an linear interpolation to find U (internal energy). The T values are the first column, the P values the first row, and the rest are U values.

I updated with the actual values in the table. Sorry for all the confusion and thanks for the help.

Comment: @LC4Tigers: So you need a 2D interpolation?